# How to create a percentage tile for phone's battery in Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, battery

In Windows 8.1 Mobile I was able to put percentage tile for Phone's battery level on start screen. I can't do it on Windows 10 Mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Battery X app ([Free](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/battery-x/9nblggh4wlgx) or [Pro](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/battery-x-pro/9nblggh4s2nc)), its best for windows 10. the live tile also show the battery percentage with remaining standby time.

Comment: Then this can't be done natively without third party apps. Stupid Microsoft killed many useful features in Windows 8.1 Mobile on Windows 10 Mobile and insists on not bringing them back.